# How do I see my name in the panel in Gnome Shell?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I have Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 LTS and from installation, my name has not appeared in the panel. I have enabled it via dconf in `org.gnome.desktop.privacy`, but it has yet to appear even after a re-login and restart.

Can I receive some assistance into the cause of this and a solution?

This is where I would like it to appear:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the username is no longer displayed in the top panel (that `dconf` key only applies to the menu now, as the description shows). If you do wish to have it shown there, [install this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/807/simple-name/).

Unfortunately, that extension lists compatibility for only a single version of GNOME Shell (`3.10.4`). So we'll need to update the list for it to work:

```bsh
wget https://extensions.gnome.org/download-extension/simple-name@rmariano.github.com.shell-extension.zip?version_tag=3835 -O simple-name@rmariano.github.com.shell-extension.zip
mkdir simple-name@rmariano.github.com
cd simple-name@rmariano.github.com
unzip simple-name@rmariano.github.com.shell-extension.zip
sed -i 's/"3.10.4"/&, "'$(gnome-shell --version | awk '{print $3}')'"/' metadata.json
cd -
mv simple-name@rmariano.github.com .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

(You could also manually obtain the version using `gnome-shell --version`, then update the `metadata.json` file using an editor.)

Then restart GNOME Shell (press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>r</kbd>, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Then use `gnome-tweak-tool` to enable the extension:

[image]

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.12.2
```

---

An explanation:

- The [Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/807/simple-name/) website doesn't offer a way to download the extension directly. So we have to [manually fish the download link](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/76-gnome/283-gnome-shell-install-extension-command-line-script) and download it.
- The zip file so downloaded doesn't have a top level directory, so I create one, following the convention I saw in `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`: `name@website`. Then unzip the file.
- `metadata.json` is a [JSON](http://json.org/) file. This attribute is what we're looking for:

  ```
  "shell-version": [
    "3.10.4"
  ],
  ```

  I used [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sed.1.html) to look for `"3.10.4"`, then append the current version obtained via `$(gnome-shell --version | awk '{print $3}')` to it. `gnome-shell --version` usually prints `GNOME Shell x.y.z`, so I use [`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gawk.1.html) to get the third field (`x.y.z`). JSON arrays take the form `[a,b,c,...]`, so all I need to do is add `,"x.y.z"` to the existing entry.
- Move the extension to the proper directory, then restart the shell for it to be noticed, since this wasn't done through the GNOME Shell interface.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I have installed it, when I re-login it's gone, not there. I don't believe it has installed in any of my attempts. I have tried to install another extension and it worked fine without a re-login.

Comment: Curious, what distribution and if different to default, DE do you use?

Comment: @CheddieMerai I use Arch Linux, with Gnome Shell and GDM. Also, see the update.

Comment: Thank you problem solved. In as much as I appreciate the help in solving a problem I like to understand what was done and why it was done, if possible, can you explain your solution and if a source is available, can you post it?

Comment: @CheddieMerai done.

Comment: I appreciate what you have done. Is the contact info on your website valid? I want to contact you if it's possible.

Comment: @CheddieMerai yes, it's valid. Use the GMail address, if you will.

Answer (score 3):

As a late update to this question, the extension [Add Username to Top Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1108/add-username-to-top-panel/) can be directly installed from the Gnome Extensions website and appears to be well maintained at the time of writing.

Comment: Current. Tested working. +1 Gnome shell 3.28.2